# jquery animate scroll top within div range

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate

I am trying to create a jquery scroll function. It currently works nicely using the window, but I want to keep it within the constraints of a div so it cant go lower or higher than the div.

Example:

```
var $scrollingDiv = $("span.top");
    $(window).scroll(function(){            
        $scrollingDiv
            .stop()
            .animate({"top": ($(window).scrollTop() + 0) + "px"}, "slow" );
    });
```

HTML

```
<div class="holder">
<span class="top">back to top</span>
<p>loads of text here</p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Jzz76/

Any help would be gratefully appreciated

Comment: do you mean sticking .top to the top of the .holder and not letting it go beyond that if the window scrolls all the way to the top?

Comment: cool, in that case you can refer to my answer below for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, change your CSS to the follow:

```
.holder span.top{
    display:block;
    z-index:999;
    right:0;
    float:right;
}
```

If you noticed, I removed `position:absolute` and `top:0` from the above declarations. This is done so that the element is still residing within the flow of the document and will not go beyond it's parent. In order to make it go to the extreme right, I simply added `float:right`.

Next, change your jQuery to this:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    var spanOffset = $('.top').offset();
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() < spanOffset.top) {
            $('.top').css({ 'position': 'static'}); 
        } else {
            $('.top').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0px'}); 
        }   
    });
});
```

The logic behind the above snippet is pretty straight forward: We get the current Y offset of the `.top` and store it in a variable. When the window scrolls, we check the Y offset against the amount of distance scrolled. If the window does not scroll, the value of `$(window).scrollTop()` is essentially 0, and therefore, `.top` remains within the parent with no alteration; if the window scrolls and the scroll distance calculated by `$(window).scrollTop()` exceeds the current Y offset of `.top`, the CSS of `.top` will then be altered to "stick" it to the top of the window.

Refer to http://jsfiddle.net/Jzz76/20/ for a working example.

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest using a plugin - all the hard work done for you! Take a look at a lightweight plugin like this one: [jQuery Scroll To](http://flesler.blogspot.com.au/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html)

More here: [BEST JQUERY SCROLL TO TOP PLUGINS](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/jquery-scroll-top-plugins/)

Comment: i don't think this has anything to do with getting the viewport to scroll to a particular element. I could be wrong, but from the looks of it, Ariel Flesler's plugin is scripted to only do that and not to fix elements to a position when a certain offset is reached. if a plugin is somehow needed, jQuery Waypoints (http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/) is a better recommendation for the scope that the OP has defined.